# Javascript Alert no muestra texto completo en

Tags: javascript

Esto parece ser un problema del explorador ya que en ambiente de desarrollo la alerta llega completa, pero cuando un usuario de pruebas mira la alerta, esta no despliega el texto completo.

El alert es un alert normal de javascript, unicamente estamos utilizando las librerias de estilo de bootstrap,

```
alert("Este es un Texto Largo y la ultima palabra desaparece");
```

Alguien sabe por que esto pueda estar sucediendo ?

---

edit: 
esto esta sucediendole al usuario en todos los navegadores, asi que puede que sea un problema con su pc en especifico ?

Comment: los alert de javascript tienen límite que difiere de explorador a explorador, es mejor armar tu propio alert

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar  [sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) para evitar estos problemas.

Comment: Qué navegador usa el usuario (o, qué navegador causa el problema)?

Comment: Pero... ¿el texto es del tamaño de *`Este es un Texto Largo y la ultima palabra desaparece`*  o es más largo? ¿Siempre desaparece solamente la última palabra? Si es así entonces puede ser alguna regla CSS o algo que se está comiendo esa última palabra.

Comment: Como @A.Cedano comenta, debes especificar si siempre desaparece la última palabra sin importar el tamaño o sólo ocurre para texto con más de N caracteres.

Comment: en los dos casos la ultima palabra es la que desaparece, pero no hay ninguna regla de estilo que este afectando las alerts, comparando la caja de texto del usuario con la mia, la del usuario siempre es mas chica.

Answer (score 1):

Lamentablemente, con la información que provees, no es posible determinar que es lo que está causando el problema. Pero en lo que si te puedo y voy a ayudar es recomendándote:

#### Bootboxjs

Es sencillo de usar, personalizable y adaptable a cualquier aplicación que quieras hacer. Además que te evitas ese tipo de problemas de compatibilidad entre navegadores.

Te dejo el enlace a la página oficial para que le eches un ojo.

http://bootboxjs.com/

#### Compatibilidad de alert() con diferentes navegadores

https://caniuse.com/#search=alert

Answer (score 1):

Saludos he generado 5 párrafos, 557 palabras, 3789 bytes y no he tenido inconvenientes:

```
<script>
alert('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor ornare nunc. Duis eu posuere libero, eget auctor orci. Curabitur a risus vel leo elementum pellentesque. Pellentesque sollicitudin ut odio sed pulvinar. Praesent et lectus lacus. Proin pharetra tincidunt tortor, nec posuere velit. Proin molestie ipsum odio, eget eleifend tortor faucibus in. Proin tristique eu mi sit amet suscipit. Pellentesque quis aliquam nibh. Etiam mi ipsum, dictum eu varius ut, suscipit vitae est. Cras in eleifend ipsum, in blandit velit. Donec suscipit efficitur nisl, eget mattis augue viverra eu. Sed iaculis erat at finibus feugiat. Phasellus ullamcorper bibendum dui, a ultrices turpis dapibus quis.Vestibulum tempor ex fermentum augue commodo luctus. Cras consequat ullamcorper lectus, et faucibus magna sodales nec. Etiam mi nisi, vulputate vitae molestie et, facilisis eu dui. Etiam mattis pellentesque bibendum. Donec elementum tincidunt sem in congue. Integer ac mauris leo. Aenean viverra lacinia purus, eget elementum arcu aliquam eget. Fusce non nibh quis odio aliquet varius eu vel neque. Cras hendrerit at erat sit amet rhoncus. Aliquam eleifend libero ac facilisis eleifend. Mauris posuere eget sapien nec pretium. Suspendisse scelerisque, lorem ac condimentum placerat, sem arcu cursus diam, sed pharetra sapien ante eget arcu. Praesent faucibus arcu in consectetur pretium. Suspendisse a arcu a risus aliquet convallis quis id velit. Nulla eu diam laoreet, varius leo non, aliquam dolor. Donec ut facilisis dolor. Cras magna dolor, facilisis quis eleifend feugiat, aliquet sit amet odio. Morbi suscipit sem ut mauris ultrices vestibulum. Praesent lacus nisl, posuere vel ullamcorper efficitur, ullamcorper at purus. Nunc vel dolor volutpat urna bibendum sagittis at et nisl. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Quisque a felis vitae erat porta mattis et ut nulla. Suspendisse tristique sit amet mauris ut semper. Phasellus iaculis posuere erat eget suscipit. Aenean non libero porta, commodo metus ac, efficitur orci. Suspendisse id tincidunt nibh, non finibus felis. Mauris at tempor nisl. Sed eu suscipit sem, nec fermentum enim. Sed fringilla felis at sodales sagittis. Curabitur eu mi et lorem congue ultricies. Maecenas tincidunt rutrum ex quis rutrum. Vivamus facilisis mi augue, vel iaculis sem rhoncus eu. Phasellus suscipit, nunc eu ultricies finibus, urna elit aliquet urna, nec fringilla risus leo eu ex. Nullam finibus sem fermentum odio lobortis dignissim. Donec porta, ligula non consectetur auctor, elit ipsum finibus est, a lacinia justo metus sit amet nunc. Quisque velit mi, dapibus vitae gravida sed, rutrum et magna. Praesent volutpat feugiat bibendum. Nam venenatis nibh non felis mollis viverra. Aliquam nisi odio, condimentum vitae nunc sed, maximus ultricies orci. ');
</script>
```

Deberias revisar tus estilos, versiones de navegadores actualizados, y por ultimo te recomiendo usar :

[SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/)

Te ayudara mucho en las alertas tienes muchos estilos para las mismas y es personalizable..!!